# Azure for Students Credits Hard Limit

Tags: azure

I have registered for the Azure for Students Offer, which gives 100$ of credits to spend for college students.
I am worried that somehow the ressources can create lots of unexpected, additional costs. 
I am only using a virtual machine and the ressources it creates automatically.

Do the services really stop working, once the credit has been fully spent for a virtual machine? Or in other words, is it safe to assume, that there will no be additional costs beyond the free credit if I only use the VM?

Answer (score 1):

From this [`link`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/free-account-students-faq/):

> What happens after I use my USD100 credit or I’m at the end of 12
>   months?
>
> **After you exhaust your available credit or reach the end of 12 months,
>   your Azure subscription will be disabled**. If you‘ve reached the end of
>   your 12 months and are still a student, you‘ll be able to renew your
>   Azure for Students offer. We’ll notify you shortly before your
>   12-month anniversary to let you know how to renew. If you’re no longer
>   a student, you may upgrade to a Pay-As-You-Go subscription by
>   contacting Azure Support.

So to answer your question, you won't be charged more than $100 unless you have upgraded to a Pay-As-You-Go Subscription.